# Ubuntu: Using curl to download an image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I want to download an image accessible from this link: `https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png` into my local system. Now, I'm aware that the `curl` command can be used to download remote files through the terminal. So, I entered the following in my terminal in order to download the image into my local system:

```
curl https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, so obviously there is some other way to download images from the Internet using `curl`. What is the correct way to download images using this command?

Comment: `However, this doesn't seem to work` what do you have as output?

Comment: see my answer for what that would output

Answer (score 178, accepted):

`curl` without any options will perform a GET request.  It will simply return the data from the URI specified. Not retrieve the file itself to your local machine.

When you do,

```
$ curl https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png
```

You will receive binary data:

```
                   |�>�$! <R�HP@T*�Pm�Z��jU֖��ZP+UAUQ@�
��{X\� K���>0c�yF[i�}4�!�V̧�H_�)nO#�;I��vg^_ ��-Hm$$N0.
���%Y[�L�U3�_^9��P�T�0'u8�l�4 ...
```

In order to save this, you can use:

```
$ curl https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png > image.png
```

to store that raw image data inside of a file.

An easier way though, is just to use `wget`.

```
$ wget https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png
$ ls
.
..
apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png
```

Comment: when download images from `google drive` they won't open as usual. But the code (`curl `) you have given works well, is it a google security measure or is there any other way?

Comment: what if I want to save the actual binary data to a file instead of getting the image?

Comment: @FabianRios, I guess it's as simple as to change the extension of the format to .txt instead of .png, I just tried and it worked.

Answer (score 66):

For those who don't have nor want to install wget, `curl -O` (capital "o", not a zero) will do the same thing as `wget`.  E.g. my old netbook doesn't have wget, and is a 2.68 MB install that I don't need.

```
curl -O https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png
```

Comment: "is a 2.68 MB install that I don't need." Now *that's* being frugal with your storage. Bravo. :)

Answer (score 29):

If you want to keep the original name — use uppercase **-O**

`curl -O https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png`

If you want to save remote file with a different name — use lowercase **-o**

`curl -o myPic.png https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png`

Answer (score 10):

Create a new file called files.txt and paste the URLs one per line. Then run the following command.

```
xargs -n 1 curl -O < files.txt
```

source: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/downloading-a-list-of-urls-automatically

Answer (score 5):

For ones who got `permission denied` for saving operation, here is the command that worked for me:

```
$ curl https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png --output py.png
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

$ curl https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png > precomposed.png

Comment: Refer stack overflow guidelines on how you post an answer, mainly how is this answer different from the others posted before you and also formatting your answer will help.

Comment: It is shorter and much clear. Downvoting is misleading because it makes the impression that the answer is wrong, but it isn't.